# Asking for help in proof of part of a Theorem in Apostol Mathematiccal Analysis ( A part which is not proved)

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

While self studying Lebesgue Integration from Apostol Mathematical Analysis I am struck on this theorem

Image->[image]

> I am not able to understand how if theorem is true for {$s_n$ - $s_1 $} then it's true for $ s_n$ also.

I tried by putting { $s_n$ -$s_1$} everywhere in theorem where I have {$ s_n$ } but if $\int_{I} f $ = lim n->$\infty$ $\int_{I} ( s_n -s_1)$ then how does integral of $s_n$ also converges to same limit of f ie $\int_{I} f $?

I am confused here and can anyone please derive the required justification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that $\{s_n-s_1\}$ converges almost everywhere on $I$ to a limit function $f$ in $U(I)$, and
$$
\int_If=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_I(s_n-s_1).
$$

Your mistake was to try to prove that $\{s_n\}$ converges to $f$. But that's not needed. You just have to prove that $\{s_n\}$ converges to an element of $U(I)$. The obvious candidate is $f+s_1$.